# jquery UI draggable element placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add a draggable image wrap inside a `<div>` to a content editable `<div>`. My problem is when I make the `<div>` draggable; it keeps the place holder. Space is reserved even if I moved the object, and I want to disable that. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
var cont = $('<div/>').draggable().attr('contenteditable',false);
var img = $('<img/>').attr('src',file.url).attr('height','100px').attr('width','150px');

img.appendTo(cont);
cont.appendTo('#front');
img.resizable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need some more code (html) to test this, but offhand I'd say try one of the following:

1) try setting the helper property to original: `$('').draggable({helper:'original'});`
2) try setting your draggable as a sortable with of course helper at original: `$('').sortable({helper:'original'});`

Also I don't see where you've connected your drag and drop zones, use the {connectWith: '.dropzone'} when you initiate your system.

I'd like to actually try it out before I tell you what to do, but that's what I'd try first.

Comment: hi, i tried that, but it seems it wont work :(, surprisingly when i make it resizable() it removes the placeholder when i try to re size it.